# Not sure how to fix unsecured content over SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

My website is [here](https://portal.thespartaninstitute.com), and visiting it in Chrome gives the 'load unsafe script' error and unsecured content errors in the console. Firefox loads the site, but there isn't a lock.

My site is entirely in PHP, and I'm not sure where to start. The console and firebug said that the site was loading unsecure scripts over HTTP, but how do I make it all HTTPS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has lots of links to `http://` resources, eg.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://portal.thespartaninstitute.com/...">
```

You need to ditch the `http:` part and just link to `//portal.thespartaninstitute.com/...` - that will then use `https` when the page has been loaded that way.

Comment: Thanks Richie. I'm just not sure where to edit that? The script itself has a globals.php that defines the 'real path' and things like that. I just don't know where to start, heh. And there's about 100 different PHP files.

Comment: @user2443803: Sorry, obviously we're not going to be able to help you with that!

Comment: Is there someway to figure out which files are calling which links, so I can track it down?

Comment: I haven't used grep before, do you think you could give me an example? Sorry. total noob.